# Django-Url error

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

```
def test(request, arg1, arg2):
   c = [[calendar.month_name[(i.date).month],i.count] for i in    
   Model_name.objects.filter(worker = arg1, process = arg2)]
   c.insert(0,['Month', 'Counts']) # It's for Chart Purpose
   return render_to_response('test3.html', {'array': json.dumps(array3)})
```

This my view and the url

```
url(r'^test/(?P<ass_name>/<process_name>\w+)/$', 'model_name.views.test', name='test')
```

throws me 404 Error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the error with traceback.

Comment: Just the common 404 error `Page not found (404)`

Comment: What url you are hitting?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/Thiliban/Ideeli/

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here:

1. You can't combine multiple URL parameters.
2. The URL parameter names must be identical to the view's parameter names.

---

So change your URL to this:

```
url(r'^test/(?P<ass_name>\w+)/(?P<process_name>\w+)/$', 'model_name.views.test', name='test')
```

And your view function to this:

```
def test(request, ass_name, process_name):
```

Comment: @ Leis: That worked, but Can you please explain me or a way I can know it?

Comment: @Thuruv It's all in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).